# Django: Filtering query from a specific index

Tags: django

I go through the Django queryset and i found many methods to limit the queryset in django

But right now  i am looking for the solution for my problem that is

suppose if i want to filter the data from id 10 to till last

```
get_meetings = Meeting.objects.all()  # will return the all meeting from 0 to last
```

i want the details of all meeting from index 10 to last 
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use the standard Python slice syntax.

```
Meeting.objects.all()[10:]
```

Comment: one more thing what if i want to limit the result from 10 index to 10 limit like Meeting.objects.all[10:10]  want work here

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be

```
Meeting.objects.filter(id__gte=10)
```